# How to convert List of Double to List of String?

Tags: java, string, list, double

This just might be too easy for all of you, but I am just learning and implementing Java in a project and am stuck with this.

How to convert `List` of `Double`  to `List` `String`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways to do this but here are two styles for you to choose from:

```
List<Double> ds = new ArrayList<Double>();
// fill ds with Doubles
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Double d : ds) {
    // Apply formatting to the string if necessary
    strings.add(d.toString());
}
```

But a cooler way to do this is to use a modern collections API (my favourite is [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)) and do this in a more functional style:

```
List<String> strings = Lists.transform(ds, new Function<Double, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Double from) {
            return from.toString();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks I used the first method !

Answer (score 6):

You have to iterate over your double list and add to a new list of strings.

```
List<String> stringList = new LinkedList<String>();
for(Double d : YOUR_DOUBLE_LIST){
   stringList.add(d.toString());
}
return stringList;
```

Comment: Thank Thomas! all of you have basically pointed to the same method .. thanks a tonne

Answer (score 5):

```
List<Double> ds = new ArrayList<>();
// fill ds with Doubles
List<String> strings = ds.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();
doubleList.add(1.1d);
doubleList.add(2.2d);
doubleList.add(3.3d);

List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Double d:doubleList)
     listOfStrings.add(d.toString());
```